# @Query for joining two tables

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to join two entities in a third one using @Query method.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.concretepage.entity.DeptEmpDto(d.departmentId,d.departmentName,d.managerId,d.locationId,e.employeeId,e.firstName,e.lastName,e.phoneNumber,e.hireDate,e.jobId,e.salary,e.commissionPct) FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Department d")
List <DeptEmpDto> fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin();
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

I cannot understand where is my mistake.Any help will be appreciated :).

Comment: You need the ON: INNER JOIN Department d **ON d.something = e.theSameSomething**, maybe d.departmentId = e.departmentId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the joining condition after joining tables using `ON` clause. So just change your query with this:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.concretepage.entity.DeptEmpDto(d.departmentId,d.departmentName,d.managerId,d.locationId,e.employeeId,e.firstName,e.lastName,e.phoneNumber,e.hireDate,e.jobId,e.salary,e.commissionPct) FROM Employee e INNER JOIN Department d on e.joining_column_from_table1=d.joining_column_from_table2")
```

> Make sure to replace `joining_column_from_table1` and
>   `joining_column_from_table2` with your column names from table
>   `Employee` and `Department`  respectively